# Put an icon after list item with :after and font awesome

Tags: css, font-awesome

I am having a problem getting the icon to appear directly after a list item in a `<ul>` using font awesome and `:after`.

The `<li>` with the active class should have the icon after it but when another `<ul>` is added in before closing the list item, it's puts the icon after the entire secondary list.

```
<div id="thirdLevMenu">
<ul>
<li class="active">Integrated Coastal Watershed Management Plans
<ul>
<li><a href="http://design-irwmp3.migcom.com/app_pages/view/7931">Russian River Integrated Coastal Watershed Management Plan</a></li>
<li><a href="http://design-irwmp3.migcom.com/app_pages/edit/http:/www.goldridgercd.com/watersheds/salmoncreekplan.html" target="_blank">Salmon Creek Coastal Watershed Management Plan</a></li>
<li><a href="http://design-irwmp3.migcom.com/app_pages/edit/http:/www.mattole.org/plan" target="_blank">Mattole Coastal Watershed Management Plan</a></li>
<li><a href="http://design-irwmp3.migcom.com/app_pages/edit/http:/www.trinidad.ca.gov/documents-library/category/30-icwmp.html" target="_blank">Trinidad-Westhaven Coastal Watershed Management Plan</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I can't for the life of me figure out what I am doing wrong.

[Here's my jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RWqTj/)

Comment: What do you expect to happen instead? When you add that second `<ul>` inside the top `<li>`, that entire inside list becomes part of the parent list item. It's doing exactly what you're telling it too, it's putting the arrow directly after the `<li>`. Do you want it to go after the "Integrated Coastal Watershed Management Plans" text instead?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment:

"When you add that second `<ul>` inside the top `<li>`, that entire inside list becomes part of the parent list item. It's doing exactly what you're telling it too, it's putting the arrow directly after the `<li>`."

If you want the icon to go after the text reading "Integrated Coastal Watershed Management Plans" instead, add a span around that title and tweak your CSS to add the `:after` pseudo element to that span instead of the entire `<li>`.

HTML

```
<li class="active">
 <span class="title">Integrated Coastal Watershed Management Plans</span>

 ...
</li>
```

CSS

```
#thirdLevMenu ul li.active .title:after{ 
   content: '\f0da';
   font-family: FontAwesome;
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;
   margin:0px 0px 0px 10px;
   text-decoration:none;

}
```

[Here's an updated fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/RWqTj/2/)

Comment: the fiddle is broken because the fontawesome.css file no longer exists. for me the font family needed to be "font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Pro'"